# How to create a dictionary that contains a name as string and errors as dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I need some help. I want to create a list (or dictionary) in C# that holds errors for each row of data that I read from each Access database. I want the error list to hold something like this (as in json):

```
{
   filename: {
         name: 'test1.mdb',
         errors: {
             'row': 1, 
             'id': 23423, 
             'error': 'something went wrong',
         }
   }
}
```

Now, I want to create a new dictionary of errors each time the row that's being read has some problem. This is what I did.

```
Dictionary<string, string> errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
errors.Add('row', '1');
errors.Add('error', 'something went wrong');
errors.Add('id', '23423');
```

Now, how can I add the above errors with the filename that the error generated from. This is what I did:

`Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> file = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
file.Add("errors", errors);`

Okay, that works for entering the errors in the dictionary, but what about the file name? I can't do

`file.Add("name", filename); <-- this won't work`

because filename is not a dictionary but a string. How can I store these information such that it contains the name of the file and the errors as dictionary?

Comment: Create a class that represents your data structure or alternatively use `Tuple<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` instead of `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: thanks for the concept. After I read your comment, I was like "oh yeah!!". I'm working on it, but @Icemanind already put in the code. I'll use that one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should break this down more. First, create an `Error` class:

```
public class Error {
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a `FileName` class:

```
public class FileName {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }

    public FileName() 
    {
        Errors = new List<Error>();
    }
}
```

Then you can add stuff, like this:

```
var file = new FileName();
file.Name = "test1.mdb";
file.Errors.Add(new Error() 
    { 
        Row = 1, 
        Id = 23432, 
        ErrorMessage = "Something went wrong!" 
    });
```

Comment: Both the creation of new classes and use of List over Dictionary seem like noteworthy improvements. Using a Dictionary here didn't seem to make sense to me... Also, Dictionaries within Dictionaries isn't the most elegant idea.

Comment: @DangerZone, that's what I thought too. Wasn't really happy with Dictionary within Dictionary, but I had to try something. I just need more practice to remember I could create Class like what Icemanind did. I did it several times, but still skipped my mind. Thanks all for help, though!